# How to move app data to external SD card without root

Tags: applications, external-sd, app2sd

I have a Karbonn A15 with Android ICS (4.0.4), it's not rooted.

I want to move the app data to my external sd card. I tried to move the `/mnt/sdcard/data` folder, just to check whether it releases any memory in the storage section in phone settings.

But the internal storage was same, there was no change. Can anyone tell me where the app data resides in the internal memory? It's fine if I can move app data manually to the external SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the app's data is stored in internal memory, below `/data/data`. You cannot access these directories/files directly if your device is not routed; same applies to moving it elsewhere.

But if your device is rooted, the keyword are *Data2SD*, *App2SD*, and *Link2SD*:

- **App2SD:** the "official" way to move your apps to the SDCard (see: [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) and [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), the latter describing it in more details). This method moves a big part of the app itself over to the SDCard. Can be used without rooting the device.
- **Link2SD:** an advanced variant of *App2SD*. This moves the entire app to the SDCard, and then creates symbolic links to the "original places" -- fooling the system to think "nothing ever happened". Requires the device to be rooted, plus a separate partition on the SDCard. See [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd) and [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) for more details.
- **Data2SD:** doesn't care for the apps, but for their data. Also requires the device to be rooted. We have no tag for that, but you might want to look up the corresponding app on Google Play: [Root # All Data2SD card.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rappsd.v1).

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to link the internal data of the app to the sd card.,completely.,it to use "[Link2sd +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.link2sdplus)" version but it was a paid app.

Comment: Could you mention a link to this app? A description wouldn't do bad either.